# Can you retrieve the sessionID of an Azure Topic/Subscription message within the Azure function it triggered?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-topics, sessionid, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I want to use the SessionId of the message added to the Topic and pulled into my Azure function via a subscription.

I assign the sessionId when I place the message in the Topic.  Is there a way for me to read the sessionId when my Azure function is triggered that the subscription has a new message?

This is the declaration of my Azure function ServiceBusTrigger.

```
  [Function("GenerateListings")]
    public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("processlisting", "generate", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection", IsSessionsEnabled = true)] string mySbMsg)
    {
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an argument `string sessionId`?

Comment: I am adding the sessionID to the message a follows:

  var tobj_Message = new ServiceBusMessage(ps_Message);
  tobj_Message.SessionId = ps_SessionID;

I am trying to find a way to retrieve that session ID when the message is sent to my Azure Function.

Comment: That's not what I meant. Adding the argument to the function signature, along with `mySbMsg`. Make sure to call it `sessionId`.

Comment: @SeanFeldman What would that look like?  Would I just add 'string sessionID' between the end brace ] and the string that starts mySbMsg? so like this


public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("processlisting", "generate", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection", IsSessionsEnabled = true)] string sessionId, string mySbMsg)
    {

Comment: @SeanFeldman so that does not work.  When I coded my trigger as shown above, the value for mySbMsg came into the sessionID field and the mySbMsg was empty.

Comment: That's odd, as it should provide all the [standard properties](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/384#issuecomment-851274777) by default. Your alternative would be to "fish" those out of the [`FunctionContext.BindingContext.BindingData`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/384#issuecomment-816746674). A 2-year-old solution 

Comment: @SeanFeldman the example you liked to us for a queue.  I am using Service Bus Topics with subscriptions and I have the session enabled on the subscriptions.

Comment: Queue or subscription, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @SeanFeldman So I think I figured it out...  I will post my solution below,

Comment: Mate, that's literally what I told you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75859644/can-you-retrieve-the-sessionid-of-an-azure-topic-subscription-message-within-the?noredirect=1#comment133825443_75859644)  Glad you're unstacked.

Comment: @SeanFeldman I did specifically ask " add 'string sessionID' between the end brace ] and the string that starts mySbMsg" - so the answer to that question was no.  The sessionID needs to come after the message.

Comment: All system properties follow after the payload. Anyhow, none of this hackery will be necessary with the work to add support for SDK types as you'll be able to receive your message as `ServiceBusReceivedMessage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So building on what Sean Feldman stated, it appears you do have access to all the standard properties.  It also appears or is important.  When I placed the sessionId before the message it did not seem to work - as shown below:

```
public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("processlisting", "generate", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection", IsSessionsEnabled = true)] string sessionId, string mySbMsg)
```

However after looking at the order of the items in the listing that Sean posted  about the standard properties -- https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/384#issuecomment-851274777 I notices that sessionId came after the message.  Thus I tried the following code and it seemed to work.

```
public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("processlisting", "generate", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection", IsSessionsEnabled = true)] string mySbMsg, string sessionId)
```

I will continue testing but so far this seems to work.

Comment: The message/payload always comes first.